# How can we distribute this Monero Stack Exchange press release in a cost effective manner?

Tags: discussion

Sample press release below. Content originated from this Azure [press release](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-blockchain-update-7/) written by fluffyponyza, which I modified prior to asking for [community feedback](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4ww6bt/draft_press_release_feedback_requested/).

Please share any recommendations for distributing this in a cost effective manner.

---

Blockchain, Aug. 9, 2016 /PRNewswire/ Monero joins Bitcoin and Ethereum as the 3rd blockchain based currency or consensus network on Stack Exchange. Stack Exchange is the largest network of websites for software developers and users to find, ask, and answer their technical questions. Stack Overflow alone serves tens of millions professional and novice programmers each month. The entire Stack Exchange Network has expanded to cover 150+ topics including Cryptography, Economics, Open Source and Project Management.

Monero is a crypto currency that is not based on the Bitcoin codebase and seeks to be the leader in privacy, security, and scalability. All Monero transactions are cryptographically untraceable and unlinkable, and there is no separate "clear" token. This enables end users to trust Monero as a private store of value and as a medium of exchange that is impervious to blockchain analysis or miner censorship.

Developers building privacy-aware or privacy-centric applications will benefit from Monero's private-by-default approach and will appreciate the small and simple metadata storage area (tx_extra) available in every transaction. Additionally, they will benefit from the standard and uncomplicated cryptography based on Daniel J. Bernstein's Curve25519 EC curve as well as EdDSA signatures.

Those building pegged off-chain or sidechain systems needn't worry about on-chain limitations, as Monero's dynamic block size algorithm grows and shrinks the block size limit based on the on-chain demand. Peg as much back to the Monero blockchain as you need!

[Monero Stack Exchange](https://monero.stackexchange.com) is a community-run question and answer site for developers and users of the secure, private and untraceable cryptocurrency Monero. Experts available to answer questions will include PhD mathematicians from [Monero Research Lab](https://lab.getmonero.org/) and many of the developers who have directly contributed to the Monero source-code repository.

Learn more by joining the open beta of Monero Stack Exchange [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Congratulations, we are in public beta mode now!

Comment: Just very small suggestions to improve readability: 1) add a horizontal line between the introduction (1st paragraph) and the content, or 2) quote the whole press release. Otherwise, make it a normal Q&A by explaining and asking the issue, and post the draft press release as an answer (community wiki, if you want to be easier to be editable by others), Finally, congrats on reaching public beta :)